# Handle and Follow Links Using Web Element in RPA Express

Tags: selenium, xpath, rpa, workfusion

I am using WorkFusion RPA Express ver. 1.1.4. While Web Web Elements can be used to get/set web elements by XPath, attributes cannot be retrieved using this method.

The framework expects to see one or more Web Elements as the result, but not the attributes. So, I end up receiving Selenium Exceptions.

I was wondering if there is a way to capture the attributes of the web elements using XPath **keeping them as web elements**.

Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href= "link1">Text 1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href= "link2">Text 2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected Result: (as a list of Web Elements)

```
link1
link2
```

Comment: There is no code that you have posted?

Comment: The RPA Express tool is a drag-and-drop type of tool with predefined actions and loops, etc. But my general questions is more about how to get web element attributes as web elements rather than the tool itself.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was some kind of framework. I have no idea about this and would not like to register to just get a download

Comment: To be fair, it is a framework with facilities to control, schedule, and monitor the bots. I was talking about the RPA Recorder, which is helping to record the bots and design them using the predefined actions.

Comment: Yes I looked at their video, had not heard of them before. I guess someone who has worked more with RPA might be able to answer. I would also suggest to post on any forum they might have till you find a solution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future releases of Workfusion RPA Express version 1.1.4 (1.2.0 is the latest version), Web elements does have a use element attributes option wherein you can the values like link1 and link2 (in your question). Please see the attached link for detailed feature in tool: https://kb.workfusion.com/display/RPAe/Web .

[image]

Comment: I haven't had a chance to check it yet, but it sounds like what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not allow attributes, that result to text, or plain text to evaluate into WebElement. Sad (no) but true.

Since Workfusion RPA wraps Selenium, you'll get the exceptions anyway.